# Python multiprocessing in FARGATE with docker exiting prematurely

Tags: python, multithreading, docker, multiprocessing, aws-fargate

We have an app implementing the python multiprocessing library. Our code runs:

```
result=pool.starmap(myfunc, params)
Pool.close()
Pool.join()
```

Usually I post more code, but this is honestly the most complicated part, it's very simple code.

We then have it deploy to an aws FARGATE instance where it runs until we get:

> STOPPED(Essential container in task exited)

Which means that, I think, the main process is exiting which is causing the whole app container to close? Can anyone confirm this? Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks!

Edit: I have updated this because it looks like this may actually be an issue with docker exiting.

Comment: My standard advice for multiprocessing is to ensure you switch to `spawn` implementation rather than default fork-before-exit. No idea if that's the issue here, but just good idea in general (https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/).

Comment: As far as specific situation—what do the logs say?

Comment: Thanks i will give this a check! Unfortunately my AWS logs are not going to the console

Comment: Getting logs working is pretty important to debugging many problems, so worth figuring out how to get those working.